# MySQL - Adding Columns to table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on the first giant update to my website. It has an existing table for posts. If I add on two columns to the table, will I be able to import the old data to the updated table?

EDIT: I meant columns. Whoops.

Comment: Do you mean two columns?

Comment: When you say "add on two rows", do you mean two **columns**? In other words, so the updated table has more fields than the imported data?

Comment: Depends on how the dump was done. It may have 'drop' instructions to delete any existing tables.

Comment: Did you mean add two *columns* to the existing table?  Yes, all rows will be preserved provided you make the new columns nullable or provide default values.

Comment: I meant columns. Whoops. Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean two columns? If they are nullable then you should be able to import your old data which doesn't contain these columns. You'll just need to write your insert statement carefully by making sure to specify the exact columns you are inserting into. This is a good practice and should be done anyway (thanks Bruno for the tip).

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM sourceTable
```

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT *
FROM sourceTable
```

If the two new columns are not nullable then you can you try appending some dummy data using literals just to get the insert to work.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3, NewCol1, NewCol2)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, '', ''
FROM oldDataTable
```

Or you could create a default constraint which will work just as well.

Comment: Nullable isn't necessary, having a default value could also be useful. (And I'd say specifying the column names in an `insert` is *always* a good idea.)

Comment: If there is no default constraint and the columns are non-nullable then his insert will fail unless he appends dummy data like in my example.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, nullable or default value would both work, not just nullable.

Comment: Thanks, I added these points to the original answer.

Comment: Thank you! I can't accept for another 7 mins so give me a few :]

Answer (score 0):

First Import the data and then add the new columns. 
Or you can insert the two columns taking care that they cann't be null, and then import the old data

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean if you add two columns to the table?

Yes you should be able to insert the existing data using `INSERT` statements as along as the new columns are nullable or you set a default value for those columns.